# How are keras tensors connected to layers that create them

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In the book "Machine Learning with scikit-learn and Tensorflow" there's a code fragment I can't wrap my head around. Until that chapter, their models were only explicitly using layers - be it in a sequential fashion, or functional. But in the chapter 16, there's this:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

encoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[None], dtype=np.int32)
decoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[None], dtype=np.int32)
sequence_lengths = keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=np.int32)

embeddings = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size)
encoder_embeddings = embeddings(encoder_inputs)
decoder_embeddings = embeddings(decoder_inputs)

encoder = keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_embeddings)
encoder_state = [state_h, state_c]

sampler = tfa.seq2seq.sampler.TrainingSampler()

decoder_cell = keras.layers.LSTMCell(512)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
decoder = tfa.seq2seq.basic_decoder.BasicDecoder(decoder_cell, sampler,
                                                 output_layer=output_layer)
final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = decoder(
    decoder_embeddings, initial_state=encoder_state,
    sequence_length=sequence_lengths)
Y_proba = tf.nn.softmax(final_outputs.rnn_output)

model = keras.models.Model(
    inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, sequence_lengths],
    outputs=[Y_proba])
```

And then he just runs the model in a standard way:

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")

X = np.random.randint(100, size=10*1000).reshape(1000, 10)
Y = np.random.randint(100, size=15*1000).reshape(1000, 15)
X_decoder = np.c_[np.zeros((1000, 1)), Y[:, :-1]]
seq_lengths = np.full([1000], 15)
history = model.fit([X, X_decoder, seq_lengths], Y, epochs=2)
```

I have trouble understanding the code starting at line 7. The author is creating an `Embedding` layer which he immediately calls on `encoder_inputs` and `decoder_inputs`, then he does basically the same with the `LSTM` layer that he calls on the previously created `encoder_embeddings` and tensors returned by this operation are used in the code slightly below. What I don't get here is how are those tensors trained? It looks like he's not using the layers creating them in the model, but if so, then how come the embeddings are learned and the whole model converges?

Comment: https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Backprop/

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the Keras [Functional API](https://keras.io/api/models/model/). In this style of defining a model, you write the blueprints first, and then use it later. Think of it like wiring a circuit: while you're connecting things, there's no electricity flowing through them (the electricity corresponds to data in our metaphor). Later, you turn on the power source, and electricity flows through.

This is how the Functional API works as well. First, let's read the last line:

```
model = keras.models.Model(
    inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, sequence_lengths],
    outputs=[Y_proba])
```

This says "Hey Keras, I need a model whose inputs are `encoder_inputs`, `decoder_inputs`, and `sequence_lengths`, and they will eventually produce `Y_proba`. The details of how they will produce this output is defined above. Let's look at the specific lines you're having trouble with:

```
embeddings = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size)
encoder_embeddings = embeddings(encoder_inputs)
decoder_embeddings = embeddings(decoder_inputs)
```

The first of these says, "Keras, give me a layer that will produce embeddings". `embeddings` is a layer object. The next two lines are the wiring that we talked about: you can connect layers preemptively before data flows through them: *that's the crux of the Functional API*. So the second layer says, "Keras, `encoder_inputs`, which is an `Input`, will connect to (and go through) the `Embedding` layer I just created, and the result of that will be in a variable I call `encoder_embeddings`.

The rest of the code follows the same logic: you're connecting the wires together, before you `compile` your model and eventually `fit` it with the data.

Comment: And even though the layers are not explicitly passed to the model, but their outputs are, their weights and biases will be updated? It seems like I'm missing something here. Is a layer added to the model execution graph at the moment of its creation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The model knows its inputs and outputs, so it follows the inputs through to the outputs to form the execution graph.